# How to resolve "cannot resolve groupBy" error message?

Tags: scala

I'm a newhand in Scala, as the topic

```
package edu.luc.cs.cs372.echo
package main

object Main extends App {
  val lines = scala.io.Source.stdin.getLines
  val words = lines.flatMap(_.split("\\W+"))
  val list2 = words.groupBy(_.length).mapValues(_.length)
  val vectorOfLengths = (1 to list2.keys.max).map(length =>list2.getOrElse(length, 0))
  for ((count, length) <- vectorOfLengths.zipWithIndex)
    println(f"${length+1}: ${"#" * count}")
```

Errors are thrown here:

```
Error:(7, 21) value groupBy is not a member of Iterator[String]
  val list2 = words.groupBy(_.length).mapValues(_.length)
                    ^

Error:(9, 43) Cannot construct a collection of type That with elements of type (A1, Int) based on a collection of type scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Nothing].
  for ((count, length) <- vectorOfLengths.zipWithIndex)
                                          ^
```

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`words` is an `Iterator`, and there is no `groupBy` method on the `Iterator` class, so you will have to convert the iterator to something else:

```
words.toVector.groupBy(_.length)
```

Comment: Two more questions, how to: 1.flush-right align the numbers of words of each length
2.scale the length of the histogram bars so that the longest bar uses up the entire current width of the console

Comment: Ask those as new questions.